# Make Mathematica not simplify an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I've run into this problem countless times, and it is making Mathematica extremely unusable for me. I input an expression into Mathematica, and it tries to simplify the expression. However, in doing so, it takes a considerable amount of time and then gives me an expression that isn't even the same! Here's the example that's currently giving me trouble: https://goo.gl/KutS4n

I can't find a way to define a function without causing Mathematica to "simplify", since Google searching is only giving me ways *to* simplify expressions.

Here is the expression giving me trouble:

```
f[n_] = 1 - ((365!)/((365 - n)!))/365^n - 
  1/365^n Sum[ 
    Binomial[365, 
      k]*((365 - k)!)/((365 - k - (n - 2 k))!)*((n!)/((n - 2 k)!))/
      2^k, {k, 1, Floor[n/2]}]
```

**Edit**
It seems this will be closed, because [Nicholas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36720/nicholas-pipitone)'s solution of just using `:=` works so well in this case.  But it doesn't address the underlying issue of why the following two lead to different answers.  What is causing this?  Is the simplification unstable when numbers as large as `365!` are used?

```
With[{n = 8},
 (1 - ((365!)/((365 - n)!))/365^n - 
   1/365^n Sum[
     Binomial[365, 
       k]*((365 - k)!)/((365 - k - (n - 2 k))!)*((n!)/((n - 2 k)!))/
       2^k, {k, 1, Floor[n/2]}])
 ]
(* 71812618834393/172615601860890625 *)

(1 - ((365!)/((365 - n)!))/365^n - 
   1/365^n Sum[
     Binomial[365, 
       k]*((365 - k)!)/((365 - k - (n - 2 k))!)*((n!)/((n - 2 k)!))/
       2^k, {k, 1, Floor[n/2]}]) /. n -> 8
```

> During evaluation of In[80]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>

```
(* Indeterminate *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, simply use `:=` to make it evaluate the expression only upon calling. This is mentioned [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html).